# C# async decorator best practices

Tags: c#, design-patterns, async-await, decorator

I have simple asynchronous service, which I need to decorate.

What is the best practice when you decorate an asynchronous method?

- should I use `async/await` in the decorator? `Example1`
- should I leave it as `Task<>` and use `await` only on the original caller?

Example

```
public interface IService
{
    Task<bool> GetStatusAsync();
}

public class Example1 : IService
{
    private readonly IService _decorated;
    public Example1(IService decorated)
    {
        _decorated = decorated;
    }

    public async Task<bool> GetStatusAsync()
    {
        // extra code

        return await _decorated.GetStatusAsync();
    }
}

public class Example2 : IService
{
    private readonly IService _decorated;
    public Example2(IService decorated)
    {
        _decorated = decorated;
    }

    public Task<bool> GetStatusAsync()
    {
        // extra code

        return _decorated.GetStatusAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html

Comment: Depends what `// extra code` is. Could it throw an exception? If so, use the keywords. If not, you could achieve a _minimal_ performance benefit from returning directly from `_decorated.GetStatusAsync()`.